# IE and firefox keep on spinning but chrome works fine and returns data from asp.net in less than 15 mins

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox

On submitting a request from an aspx page, call is made to database from asp.net server side code, the records are processed and a string in csv format is created. The page then redirects to filewriter.aspx. This page then response.binary this string.

This is the code to redirect to filewriter.aspx:

```
Dim mgr As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page)
If (Not Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("DownloadFileScript")) Then
    mgr.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType, "DownloadFileScript", sb.ToString(), True)
End If
```

There and around 200k records and file size is 47 mb when generated through chrome.
IE and Firefox keep on spinning but chrome works fine and returns data in less than 15 minutes.
In IE we see the error

> "sys webforms pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception an unknown error
>   occurred while processing 12031".

In web.config we tried setting

```
httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800" 
maxRequestLength="1048576"`
```

but to no use.

Answer (score 0):

You could spawn a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-lang=vb) that generates the report, store it in [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-lang=vb) (using a GUID created with Guid.NewGuid() as the key), and then send the browser to a URL that has that GUID as a parameter. That URL will then check whether that Task is done or not, and if its done, send the file back. The user can keep refreshing until it's done.

If this workaround doesn't get it working in IE and Firefox, but it still works in Chrome, the problem must not be related to the request time.